# Unable to connect signal from qobject

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I've created a simple class inherited from QObject and created a signal, like this:

testobject.h:

```
#ifndef TESTOBJECT_H
#define TESTOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class testObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit testObject(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    somethingChanged();

public slots:

};

#endif // TESTOBJECT_H
```

testobject.cpp:

```
#include "testobject.h"

testObject::testObject(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}
```

And then tried to make an QEventLoop that should stop when the signal is emitted:

```
testObject *foo = new testObject;
QEventLoop loop;
connect(foo, SIGNAL(somethingChanged()), loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
```

But compiler complains like this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'TestObjectHere::connect(objectTest&, const char*, QEventLoop&, const char*)'
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you renamed the class _testObject_? If so did you _run qmake_ before you tried to build your project?

Comment: No, _testObject_ is the class created by Qt Creator. I've tried to run qmake and cleaning/rebuilding my project, but with no results

Comment: Where do you call the _connect_ it's inside a QObject class? Anyway try with the fully qualified name: _QObject::connect(..._

Comment: inside `void testFunction()`, called from constructor of form. QObject::connect giving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a *pointer* to QObject:

```
connect(foo, SIGNAL(somethingChanged()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```

*edit*: the error message complains about types that are not visibile from your sample:

> error: no matching function for call to 'TestObjectHere::connect(objectTest&, const char*, QEventLoop&, const char*)'

also objectTest& should be changed to a pointer, instead of a reference. In the code posted, foo *is* a pointer, then you should have a mismatch between actual code passed to compiler and what you show.

Try to act similarly on *source*, for instance, prepend the pointer to operator, as we have done for *target*.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two: **CapelliC** 's answer and my comment:

```
QObject::connect(foo, SIGNAL(somethingChanged()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to post. Thanks, guys!